# TypeScript and ng2 rc.1 getting Error:(20, 15) TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: typescript, angular

TypeScript and ng2 rc.1 getting Error:(20, 15) TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.

when trying to use directive of module as in

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Notes1',
    moduleId: module.id,
    directives: [ModalDialog, FORM_DIRECTIVES, DisplayError],
    templateUrl: 'Notes1.html',
    styleUrls: ['Notes1.css']
})
```

any idea how to fix the TS error.. all is working fine at runtime

regards

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means TypeScript compiler doesn't know what `module` is. For a quick fix:

```
declare var require: any;
```

To make it more complete, use a definition from [DefinitelyTyped/node](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts#L43-L66):

```
interface NodeRequireFunction {
    (id: string): any;
}

interface NodeRequire extends NodeRequireFunction {
    resolve(id:string): string;
    cache: any;
    extensions: any;
    main: any;
}

declare var require: NodeRequire;

interface NodeModule {
    exports: any;
    require: NodeRequireFunction;
    id: string;
    filename: string;
    loaded: boolean;
    parent: any;
    children: any[];
}

declare var module: NodeModule;
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I already did the same fix ```declare var module: NodeModule;``` but I was wondering (sorry I was not more explicit on my question) why isn't it part of an @angular2 import statement like the rest of the platform, regards

Comment: The module object is defined in NodeJS and declared within the Node declaration file. You either don't have this declaration file or you are not referencing it correctly in your tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score -1):

The way I fixed this was to simply add Id after module like this "moduleId": "commonjs", in my tsconfig file and the error went away!

Hope this helps,
Jim